# How to get a blob path name container name from configuration file

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I  am using .net core and using 
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Containername"))

I would like to get the container name from the configurations for the function. As of right now I have the container name "t-w-parser" hard coded like this.

```
public static void Run([BlobTrigger("t-w-parser/{name}", Connection = 
"AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
{
 log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n 
Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
}
```

How can I go about adding the container name and adding it in this part of the code?
BlobTrigger("t-w-parser/{name}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set it to

```cs
[BlobTrigger("%Containername%/{name}", ...
```

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#binding-expressions-example